# What this RewriteRule means/does?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed WordPress multisite on my server and I am under troubles with Apache, because for some reason doesn't read a CSS file, that exists, and the URL to this file is totally correct.

Due to this issue, I try to understand what the `.htaccess` file does and I have stack to this `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

I know what the `-` and the `[L]` does but I cannot understand what the `^` does.

Just in case, the previews lines in `.htaccess` file are the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is shorthand for "in all cases". Mainly used with `RewriteCond` before.

Example:

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

So, doing nothing in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I thought was the purpose of `^`, but once I was not sure for that, and I couldn't find anything, I asked. Thanks a lot for your answer !! :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I was able to help a little.